# Multiple Instances of an audio visualizer

Tags: javascript, audio

this is my first post on Stack Overflow, but I have used this site as a resource many times before.

I have a bit of code that I learned by watching a tutorial, and it works fantastic. The code makes a visualization of whatever audio frequency the passed file has. However when I tried to make a second instance of the audio visualizer it does not work out very well, which I expected. The problem is I haven't been able to figure out how to convert the code from single use to multiple file use.

If more information is needed please let me know and I will provide it. I'm thinking I need to alter the event listener in some way, but I am lost as to how.

Here is the JavaScript I am using to make the visualizer:

```
//create a new instance of an audio object and adjust some of its properties
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "audio_file_goes_here.mp3";
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = false;
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

// establish all the variables that the analyser will use
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;

// initilize the MP3 player after the pages loads all of the HTML into the window
window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);

function initMp3Player(){
  document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
  context = new AudioContext();
  analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);
  frameLooper();
}

//frameLooper animates nay style of graphics at 60fps based on browser
function frameLooper(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
  fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00CCFF";
  bars=100;
  for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++){
    bar_x = i * 3;
    bar_width = 2;
    bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
    ctx.fillRect (bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML segment that corresponds to that

```
<div id="mp3_player">
                <div id="audio_box"> </div>
                <canvas id="analyser_render"> </div>
```

and here is the CSS

```
div#mp3_player{
  width:510px; 
  height:70px; 
  background: #000;       
  padding:5px;
  margin:50px auto;
}
div#mp3_player > div > audio{
  width:500px; 
  background: #000;
  float:left;
}

div#mp3_player > canvas {
  width:500px;
  height:30px; 
  background:#002d3c;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Might be useful for you to create a code example that someone could edit, perhaps on jsfiddle.net or codepen.io

Comment: What have you tried? And is there a specific problem you are running into? People are not going to refactor some code for you.

Comment: I have a code pen I just put up that might shed some light on the problem. Right now I am trying to get two instances of the viewer working. I've attempted switching over some of the id's to classes since they are referenced multiple times in the attempt. The problem is that the second view I try to make is broken. http://codepen.io/atadsp/pen/pbKyQA

Comment: I did some work on the code pen, and I managed to get two instances of the audio visualizer working, however the code is rediclusly wet because I basically doubled the entire entry. I'm going to work for a bit on seeing how I can dry the code a bit.  http://codepen.io/atadsp/pen/pbKyQA